# Not able to read data over serial port using python

Tags: python, raspberry-pi3, pyserial

I am new to python and serial communication and trying to read data from Contect CMS50D Plus over serial connection.

I tried following and unable to get it work.
I am just able to send the data and not able to retrieve any data from the device.

```
import serial
ser = serial.Serial("COM4",baudrate=115200,parity=serial.PARITY_NONE,stopbits=1,xonxoff=True)
ser.write(serial.to_bytes([0x7D,0x81,0xAF,0x80,0x80,0x80,0x80,0x80,0x80]))

while True:
    data = ser.readline()
```

[image]

I need the following data which I sniffed.
[image]

Comment: Maybe try reading single bytes instead of an entire line. Reading a line depends on getting a line ending.

Comment: Hii I tried ser.read(1), still not able to get any data.

Comment: I am new to python and serial communication and as per my understanding ser.read(1) or ser.read(10) will able to read first 1 byte or 10 bytes and Once the data 7D 81 AF 80 80 80 80 80 80 sent over serial communication the device should be able to send the data back which I can able to read from the sniffer which is not happening.

Comment: ser.write(b'\x7d\x81\xa1\x80\x80\x80\x80\x80\x80')   I figured out I was sending wrong data